# Can I save a unique ID in paypal side like invoice_id after paypal popup closes

Tags: javascript, paypal, paypal-buttons

I need to store my application's transaction id in paypal console. ie for every transaction i need to save this id and i need to check the respective transaction in paypal console using this id. I will get this transaction id only after closing the paypal popup. I hear that we can use invoice_id for this. But unfortunate invoice_id can pass only to createOrder. Is ther any option to pass this after paypal popup closes. ie in authorize call or anything. Or is there any other solution. Please help

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend doing your createOrder itself on the server side, and setting an invoice_id at that time, rather than patching the order object, which adds much undesired complexity.

Create two routes on your server, one for 'create an order' and one for 'capture order', documented here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/

The best approval flow to pair with the above is this one: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

---

If, for some strange reason, you insist on the requirement of patching the invoice_id in *after* approval, then you would need your 'capture order' route to do an additional (third) API call before that final capture, to patch it in. You can see an update order example here: https://www.paypal.com/apex/product-profile/ordersv2/updateOrder . But don't do this.